# windows server 2008, how to make folder writable for my asp.net mvc3 app?

Tags: windows, asp.net-mvc-3, windows-server-2008, folder-permissions

I have an asp.net mvc3 application. it uploads image and resizes it.  my upload folder, i need to make it writable.  I try to do it from filezilla, set them to 777, it wont work.

I have root access to my windows server. I right click on the folder, choose property, then click on security tab.  I see 4 groups there.

creator owner, system, admin, users. what should I do from there?

Comment: This question is better suited for [ServerFault](http://serverfault.com), as it's not really a programming question. (It's a server configuration question.) Just FYI, though: Windows doesn't use `chmod` to set access rights, so `777` is meaningless, and doesn't have `root` access (it uses `adminstrator` and `admin rights`). It might be helpful when asking questions to use the proper terminology. :-)

Comment: Find out what user your web application is running under by looking at it's Application Pool (if IIS) and add that user to the folder in question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to do something similar, but I was using a folder as a temp location and not a permanent resting place for my images. For this I created a new folder inside of my app_data folder and did my file system manipulations in there.